# C# PropertyGrid DoubleClick event capture

Tags: c#, events, click, propertygrid, double-click

For a project I am working on, I have some values in a PropertyGrid that are many lines long.  I want the user to be able to double-click a *value* in the grid, which will bring up my custom UI window.  I already have it set up so that the UI works when the [...] button is clicked, but I also need it to show up directly if any grid item is double-clicked.

On a side note, looping through the controls of the PropertyGrid and assigning Click/Mouse events to them allows this to happen when the property *name* is clicked, but still does not capture the click when the property *value* is clicked.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do any of these help?  [Custom dialog for a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359690/how-can-i-force-the-propertygrid-to-show-a-custom-dialog-for-a-specific-property), [Multiline string editor dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130032/multi-line-string-in-a-propertygrid), [Modal form editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016239/how-to-create-custom-propertygrid-editor-item-which-opens-a-form)?  I'm not 100% sure this question is a dupe; please check 'em out and edit your question to let us know if and which one answered it for you.  Thanks.

Comment: You can't get to the PropertyGridView class, the control that draws the grid.  A reference is in the private "gridView" field, if you want to hack it with Reflection.