# Making a custom control's property input like that of a multiline textbox

Tags: c#, custom-controls, propertygrid

Say I have attribute "Address", how can I make it's input in the form designer's property box like that of a text box's text input, like so:

[image: Textbox input image.]

?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130032/multi-line-string-in-a-propertygrid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decorate your `Address` property with an [EditorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx) referencing the [MultilineStringEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.multilinestringeditor.aspx) class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Design;

[Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
    typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public string Address
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: I was looking at UITypeEditors and never found this.. Thanks :)

Comment: @frederic-hamidi : How to set editor to RightToLeft for Arabic text ?

Answer (score 1):

This happens through a "designer". For `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` that designer is:

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.TextBoxDesigner, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"), SRDescription("DescriptionTextBox"), ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
```

If you want to view its source code, open up .NET Reflector, Open Cache... System.Design, navigate (or search) to `System.Windows.Forms.Design.TextBoxDesigner`.

**UPDATE:** Since 2014, the .NET Core is open-source, check out the [official repository site](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/)